# Maven: how do I reference a *-bin.zip?

Tags: maven, activemq-classic

I'm trying to fetch the following apache-activemq file through maven-dependency-plugin:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/apache-activemq/5.13.2/

But it ends in a -bin.zip. What do I need to add to correctly reference this? My maven-dependency-plugin entry for this artifact is the following:

`<artifactItem>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>${activemq-install.version}-bin</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <outputDirectory>${assembly.folder}</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>`

Comment: Try removing `-bin` from the version and adding an additional `<classifier>` element with value `bin`

Comment: I think its the <classifier>bin</classifier> that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-bin` is called a "classifier". Classifiers allow for multiple artifacts with the "same" name.

You want to add `<classifier>bin</classifier>` to your dependency or artifactItem in order to reference it, instead of putting it in the version.

See the "classifier" part of the [Dependencies section in the Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!